# Let $ Q $ be a $ p$ -group and let $ N $ be a nontrivial, elementary abelian normal subgroup of $ Q $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ Q $ be a $ p$ -group and let $ N $ be a nontrivial, elementary abelian
normal subgroup of $ Q $ which has a complement $ X $ in $ Q $. If $ Q = \langle y \rangle X $ for some element $ y $, then $ \vert N \vert = p $ if $ p $ is odd and $ \vert N \vert \leq 4 $ if $ p = 2 $.

For proof, Assume that $ Q $ is a counterexample of minimal order.  Let $ p > 2 $, Let $ 1 \neq t \in N \cap Z(Q) $. Why the result is true for the group $ Q / \langle t \rangle $? and why $ \vert N \vert = p^{2} $ ? this is problem for me in this proof.

Comment: If $p>2$ then you cannot have $|N|=2$, so I do not understand your question. The result is true for $Q/\langle t \rangle$ because you chose $Q$ to be a minimal counterexample.

Comment: $ \vert  N \vert = p^2  $? this is true ? why ?

Comment: Because the theorem is true in $Q/\langle t \rangle$ and hence $|N\langle t \rangle/\langle t \rangle| = p$, so $|N|=p^2$.